# how to get a particular data from a function return

Tags: vb.net

I have a method in my class which returns a list of data's

```
Private Function GetCertificationLevels() 
            Dim theProgramYearID As Int32 = Convert.ToInt32(lstProgramYear.SelectedValue)
            Dim thePositionGroupID As Int32 = Convert.ToInt32(lstPositionGroup.Selected)
            Dim theCategoryID As Int32 = Convert.ToInt32(lstCategory.SelectedValue)
            filterLevels = _curTree.GetCertificationLevelsList(theProgramYearID, thePositionGroupID, theCategoryID)
            Return filterLevels
        End Function
```

I would like to retrieve the _data value only (which are **5261,5263,5262,5264 and 5260**)

How to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right, then you are trying to use the values of the variables `theProgramYearID`, `thePositionGroupID`, and `theCategoryID` in another procedure. I would create an overloaded procedure that contains `ByRef` arguments, and then use them in the other procedure.

```
Private Sub CallingProcedure()
    'Declare variables to hold the ByRef results.
    Dim locYearID, locGroupID, locCategoryID as Integer

    'Call the procedure, and pass the variables for processing
    Dim FunctionResult = GetCertificationLevels(locYearID, locGroupID, locCategoryID)

    'Now do whatever you need with the modified variables
    SomeOtherProcedure()
End Sub

Private Overloads Function GetCertificationLevels(ByRef theProgramYearID as Int32, ByRef thePositionGroupID as Int32, ByRef theCategoryID as Int32) 
    theProgramYearID = Convert.ToInt32(lstProgramYear.SelectedValue)
    thePositionGroupID = Convert.ToInt32(lstPositionGroup.Selected)
    theCategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(lstCategory.SelectedValue)
    filterLevels = _curTree.GetCertificationLevelsList(theProgramYearID, thePositionGroupID, theCategoryID)
    Return filterLevels
End Function
```

The `ByRef` will ensure that the function is modifying the variables passed to it, and they will have the values assigned to them in the function.

Comment: This is how i proceeded to solve this question, thanks for your time and effort

Comment: can you please look into my this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364276/value-of-type-integer-cannot-be-converted-to-1-dimensional-array?noredirect=1#comment43181074_27364276

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ:

```
Return filterLevels.Select(Function(t) t.Data).ToList()
```

Comment: instead of using LINQ is there any other way? because I have to pass the value to a method as integer

Comment: I am not using LINQ any where in the project so far