# value of type integer cannot be converted to 1-dimensional array

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Curriculum is an  .asmx file which has list of web service methods to return particular values, and this method GetMyEmployeeId is one such webmethod i will be calling from my webform,  which returns an array containing current user (homepage) id

```
Public Function GetMyEmployeeId() As Integer()
            Return New Integer() {Current.HomepageUserId}
End Function
```

I would like to call this webservice method in my webform and have to get the current employeeID, so that I can pass it to my different method which is DoSomething(here it takes the returned employeeID as parameter)

_curTree is the object of the curriculum class.

```
    Private Function GetEmployeeActual() As Items
    Dim item as Items       
    Dim employeeID As Integer()
                    'I am guessing that, am declaring the employeeID wrong ( it should not be an integer datatype may be because the GetMyEmployeeID returns an array of current user ID's)
    employeeID = _curTree.GetMyEmployeeId()
    item = DoSomething(employeeID)
                    'I am getting the error here as"value of type integer cannot be converted to 1-dimensional array"
    Return item
    End Function
```

Pls help me to proceed

Comment: you have 4 methods apparently doing much the same thing (GetMyEmployeeId, GetEmployeeActual, GetEmployeeActual and GetMyEmployeeId).  `GetMyCurrentEmployeeID` isnt shown, but `GetMyEmployeeId` returns an integer array (`Integer()`) which may be the problem.

Comment: Are you calling the correct function? I would expect a function which returns `employeeIDFiltter` [sic] to be named something more like `GetMyCurrentEmployeeFilter`.

Comment: Why are you creating an array employeeID, why are there () after Integer?

Comment: I am sorry, i have updated the final method, I would like to get the employeeID and pass it on to a function which needs it. the function GetMyEmployeeId is a webservice method, which i have to call in my webform ( and this function returns an array of current users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is caused because you are trying to pass as a parameter or function return value a single integer when it expects an array. You didn't include enough in your code to be more specific. (Which line is the error on? What is employeeIDFilter? What is DoSomething?)

Comment: kindly have a look at the edited post, i have added brief explanation

Comment: Sorry my bad, I just realised that I tried to convert Integer() into Integer32